# How to add values to array in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have below array where i am appending values to string strOrderArr.

```
  var strOrderArr = '';
            $.each(uploadData, function (i, item) {
                strOrderArr = strOrderArr + "{";
                strOrderArr = strOrderArr + "'upld_contentlabel':" + "'" + item.label + "'" + ",";
                strOrderArr = strOrderArr + "'upld_DocumentName':" + "'" + item.DocName + "'" + ",";
                strOrderArr = strOrderArr + "'upld_docid':" + "'" + item.DocId + "'" + ",";
                strOrderArr = strOrderArr + "'upld_contentvalue':" + "'" + item.value + "'";
                strOrderArr = strOrderArr + "'upld_contentid':" + "'" + item.doc_contentid + "'";
                //strOrderArr = strOrderArr + "'TotalCost':" + "'" + $(item).find("#lblTotalAmt_" + row).text() + "'";
                strOrderArr = strOrderArr + "},";

            });
```

I want to append one more value to strOrderArr from other array

```
  $.each(Content, function (key, value) {
 strOrderArr=strOrderArr+value.doc_contentid;

});
```

Is this possible? I tried as above but values are not appending. So where i going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read about `JSON.stringify(OBJECT)`.. You have put so much efforts but they are not really needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var object1 = {
  apple: 0,
  banana: { weight: 52, price: 100 },
  cherry: 97
};
 
// Assuming JSON.stringify - not available in IE<8
$( "#log" ).append( JSON.stringify( object1 ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
```